# Multi-field operations in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I started looking at elasticsearch and I am wondering if this operation could be done with it: (I did some searches but I admit I don't know what to look for).

I have contacts data like these two:

```
{
  "id"     : "id1",
  "name"   : "Roger",
  "phone1" : "123",
  "phone2" : "",
  "phone3" : "980"
}

{
  "id"     : "id2",
  "name"   : "Lucas",
  "phone1" : "789",
  "phone2" : "123",
  "phone3" : ""
}
```

I am interested to know if elasticsearch can help me find phone number duplicates even if they are in different phone fields ("123" here is present in both records).
I already saw that I can do a search for a string in multiple fields so if I search for 123 I can get these two records as a result. However, I would like the ability to issue a request which could return me something like this:

```
{
  "phones" : {
    "123" : ["id1", "id2"],
    "980" : ["id1"],
    "789" : ["id2"]
  }
}
```

Or even this would be useful (number of contacts with the number):

```
{
  "phones" : {
    "123" : 2,
    "980" : 1,
    "789" : 1
  }
}
```

Any idea if this is possible? That would be awesome if it could do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with DrTech's advice to change your data structure. But if you, for some reason, prefer to leave it as is, you could achieve the same result using multi fields terms facet:

```
curl "localhost:9200/phonefacet/_search?pretty=true&search_type=count" -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "tag" : {
            "terms" : {
                "fields" : ["phone1", "phone2", "phone3"],
                "size" : 10
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

The result would look like this:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "facets" : {
    "tag" : {
      "_type" : "terms",
      "missing" : 2,
      "total" : 4,
      "other" : 0,
      "terms" : [ {
        "term" : "123",
        "count" : 2
      }, {
        "term" : "980",
        "count" : 1
      }, {
        "term" : "789",
        "count" : 1
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do that! Nice!

Comment: wow nice one ! since you both suggested to change schema anyway is there any drawbacks/performance issue with what your proposed ? I would prefer keeping the label of the fields (which are in fact more like modile_phone, home_phone, etc...)

Comment: I was just thinking that, from schema design perspective, if you are using phone fields as an array, it might be better to represent it in elasticsearch as an array. I cannot think of any significant performance issues in your schema comparing to what DrTech proposed. In one case elasticsearch will have to read 3 fields and merge the results, and in another 1 field with size equal to 3 fields. Merging shouldn't be that expensive comparing to reading and keeping field values in the memory.

Comment: I would accept both answers but this one match my question more. Thanks you both, I already love elasticsearch !^^

Comment: I read and experimented with the es queries a little more and now fully understands what your query does but I have another issue. Do you know if the results can be restricted not by size but by count, for example returning every phone present in at least 2 records ?(I already found how to order but cannot find if any filtering on the result is possible).

Comment: I don't think terms facets support that at the moment. You will, probably, have to do it on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You could get there using a [terms facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-facet.html), but you'd have to change your data structure to include all the phone numbers in a single field:

Create your index:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/?pretty=1'
```

Index your data:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "name" : "Roger",
   "id" : "id1",
   "phone" : [
      "123",
      "980"
   ]
}
'

curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "name" : "Lucas",
   "id" : "id2",
   "phone" : [
      "789",
      "123"
   ]
}
'
```

Search on all fields, returning the count of terms in `phone`:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "facets" : {
      "phone" : {
         "terms" : {
            "field" : "phone"
         }
      }
   }
}
'

# {
#    "hits" : {
#       "hits" : [
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "name" : "Roger",
#                "id" : "id1",
#                "phone" : [
#                   "123",
#                   "980"
#                ]
#             },
#             "_score" : 1,
#             "_index" : "test",
#             "_id" : "StaJK9A5Tc6AR7zXsEKmGA",
#             "_type" : "test"
#          },
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "name" : "Lucas",
#                "id" : "id2",
#                "phone" : [
#                   "789",
#                   "123"
#                ]
#             },
#             "_score" : 1,
#             "_index" : "test",
#             "_id" : "x8w39F-DR9SZOQoHpJw2FQ",
#             "_type" : "test"
#          }
#       ],
#       "max_score" : 1,
#       "total" : 2
#    },
#    "timed_out" : false,
#    "_shards" : {
#       "failed" : 0,
#       "successful" : 5,
#       "total" : 5
#    },
#    "facets" : {
#       "phone" : {
#          "other" : 0,
#          "terms" : [
#             {
#                "count" : 2,
#                "term" : "123"
#             },
#             {
#                "count" : 1,
#                "term" : "980"
#             },
#             {
#                "count" : 1,
#                "term" : "789"
#             }
#          ],
#          "missing" : 0,
#          "_type" : "terms",
#          "total" : 4
#       }
#    },
#    "took" : 5
# }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but I was curious if there was another way. Changing the schema of the stored data is not a problem currently so I will follow your advice.